# Photon PUN: How should the objects be destroyed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I'm pretty confused about when to trigger an RPC. What I have right now is:

Player 1 is the server/host, and player 2 is the client. Both of them can shoot down enemy jets that are spawned at random. Player 1 (host) is always the one that spawns enemies, and it's done via `PhotonNetwork`:

```
if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
{
    PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(enemyPrefab.name, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

When any of the players shoot, a bullet is instantiated from the player's instance (host/client - whoever shoots), and this is done through PhotonNetwork.Instantiate as well:

```
// Update method in PlayerController.cs
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift))
{ 
    PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(bulletPrefab.name, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

And the bullet just travells until it hits an enemy, or becomes invisible. When the bullet becomes invisible, I just use the Destroy method without any network.

```
// BulletController.cs
private void OnBecameInvisible()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

So this means that, every player is tracking the bullet of every other player, and is destroying every bullet that goes out of view, right? I tried only doing it on master with `PhotonNetwork.Destroy()` but this throws error when the bullet is instantiated by clients becaue server doesn't own this instance of the bullet. So, is it normal to let each client track every bullet and destroy it? What is the best way to remove this object please?

Similarly, I have the issue with removing enemies too. The enemies can be killed by any player's bullet, but they are all spawned from the server, so what I have now is, when any bullet hits a player, I:

- `OnTriggerEnter` Destroy the bullet if it's mine through RPC (this works okay - all clients remove the bullet)
- Try to remove the enemy, again `onTriggerEnter`, with:

  ```
  if (collision.tag.ToLower() == "player")
  {
        view.RPC(nameof(RpcDestroyGameObject), RpcTarget.All);
  }
  ```

But somehow, the enemies won't get removed every time when client hits it. When server hits it, it gets removed immediately. If I try to use `PhotonNetwork.Destroy()` here, I get a ton of errors and I'm not sure how to test or debug a network game.

So, I guess the question is: How do I remove an object created on Master when a client triggers it?

Answer (score 0):

Usually `PhotonNetwork.Destroy()` should work, but in case it doesn't add a simple script to the bullet called "`Destroyer`" or something. In it use an **RPC** to Destroy the object (*This requires PhotonView component on the object*)

```
public void DestroyOnNetwork()
{
     GetComponent<PhotonView>().RPC("NetworkDestroy", RpcTarget.AllBuffered);
}

[PunRPC]
private void NetworkDestroy()
{
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

Dont forget to use `Photon.Pun`